# How can I authenticate a Post Request with Token Authentication?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Right now I can successfully authenticate patch, get and delete so only the user that has access to the object can do it. But I have a simple problem:
-How can I authenticate POST request?
For example:
User should be able to only create an ArticleImage linked to Article if both of their authors are the same, so User 2 cannot add an object to Article if User 1 is the owner.
And also we want to make sure that User 2 can't do POST request in the name of User 1.

**Model.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='articles')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class ArticleImage(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images',null=True,blank=True, validators=[validate_file_extension])
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True, related_name='articleimages')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='articleimages')
```

**View.py**

```
class ArticleImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = ArticleImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleImageSerializer
    filter_backends = [ArticleFilterBackend]
```

**Filter.py**

```
class ArticleFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(article__author=request.user)
```

Update: **Serializer.py**

```
class ArticleImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = ArticleImage
        fields = ('id','image','article')

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    articleimages_set = ArticleImageSerializer(source='articleimages',required=False,many=True)  

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id','author','caption','articleimages_set')
```

Update 2:

**Post Request**

```
'article':'articleid',
'image':'image.path',
```

**Headers**

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',"Authorization" : "Token $token"
```

It used to work without `def validate()`.
Now i get `'Article object (385395ec-dec8-472f-973f-b4f27755a658)” is not a valid UUID'.`

Comment: Can you share your serializer? You must be passing the article pk in the `ArticleImageViewSet` post. You can use that to validate

Comment: Check the update please

Comment: Since you want to link the article to the image, you need to also pass the article id in the request data for creating an image right?

Comment: Yes. Thats what i want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in your serializer:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError


class ArticleImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = ArticleImage
        fields = ('id','image','article')

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        if attrs['article'].author != self.context['request'].user:
            raise ValidationError('Article does not belong to current user')
        return attrs
```

In the serializer, you have access to `request` via `self.context['request']` which then means you can compare the article's author to the current user, that is,`self.context['request'].user`.

Comment: Updated. Try again